# Excel formulas on triming a cell value

Tags: excel, formulas, trim

I want to trim a row in excel which contains the following values:

```
row a                row b
texas/dallas         5
texas/austin         10 
california/sf        5
california/la        20
```

to

```
row a                  row b
texas                  5
texas                  10
california             5
california             20
```

Comment: You can always perform Text To Columns on column A and use the `/` sign as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is get the value of everything to the left of the `/` symbol in a particular field. To do that, you can use the following formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)
```

where `A1` is the cell you want to change.

Here's how it works:

`Find("/", A1)` finds the first instance of the "/" in the text in `A1` and returns it's position.

Then `Left(A1, <#>)` takes all the characters to the left of position calculated by the previous expression.